# Lambda getResult()

Tags: java, android

I came across the following bit of code online which I can't figure it out:

```java
mFoo.bar(future -> {
    Bundle result = future.getResult();
    boolean success = result.getBoolean(Foo.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT);
    if (success) {
        showToast("success");
    } else {
        showToast("failure");
    }
});
```

The `bar` method takes a callback argument, and a lambda expression is passed in. But I don't understand what this line is doing:

```java
Bundle result = future.getResult();
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the type of 'future' from the specification of 'bar()'.  Presumably that type has a 'getResult()' that returns a 'Bundle'.  What does the documentation say>

In general, a 'future' represents the eventual result of an asynchronous computation. For likely-similar functionality, see [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).  There is a 'get()' method to block until the completion of the computation, and then return the result of that computation.